# Good resources for finding intents from strings using NLP

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I am looking to decode intents from many strings from many conversations I have stored in a database, so I can use machine learning to create an intelligent chatbot. I have heard and tested tools like Amazon Lex, but I am looking to receive the intent from a string not create my own intents. Here is a sample starting question from the data I am working with:

Hi, can I please find out the location of the nearest Depot to Meadow Springs WA 6210?

Is there any chance we could get 34 cases from Melbourne to Sydney by Friday. I am hoping it will be a Sydney to Sydney tomorrow but if not can anyone do this by Friday from Melbourne?

can you tell me how the warranty claim is going on booking number 9528 thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "receive the intent from a string not create my own intents"? Do you mean you want to just pass a string and get an intent without doing any setup or configuration?

Comment: Also, for your sample questions, what kind of output do you want?

Comment: Yeah I am looking to just pass a string and receive an intent, as I have many intents in my data set. In terms of output for the first question, it would be nice if they knew the intent was looking for a location and recorded address that the user posted. For the third questions, I would just want to know that the inquiry is about the customers booking number.

Comment: There's no standard way to do that. Intents are usually extracted by first defining them and then classifying input based on which intent it's closest to. Since your intents seem relatively common it's possible you could find an existing service where they're already defined but I don't know of any. For an explanation of how intents can be implemented see [here](https://chatbotslife.com/text-classification-using-algorithms-e4d50dcba45). With your data, you could label inputs to create a training set.

Answer (score 1):

Intents are usually created for a specific application by providing examples. However, some services do provide pre-defined intents you can use.

- [LUIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-use-prebuilt-domains) provides prebuilt "domains" which include some place related queries
- [Snips](https://snips.ai/) has an "intents library" that you can use

That may be able to get you started. If that doesn't work, [this](https://chatbotslife.com/text-classification-using-algorithms-e4d50dcba45) guide to a from-scratch implementation may be useful.